# Remove element from array when checkbox is unchecked (filter method is not working?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this stateful variable

```
const [validMonths2019, setValidMonths2019] = useState([])
```

Now when the checkboxed is checked the event handler will get called

```
   <Form.Check label='Januar 2019' id='2019' onChange={(event) => handleCheck('01', event)} />
```

This is the event handler

```
  function handleCheck (value, event) {
    const months2019 = [...validMonths2019]
    if (event.target.id === '2019' && event.target.checked) {
      console.log(value) // value is 01
      months2019.push(value)
      setValidMonths2019(months2019)
    } else if (event.target.id === '2019' && !event.target.checked) {
      console.log(value) // value is 01
      months2019.filter(item => item !== value)
      console.log(months2019)// months2019 is still the same array.
      setValidMonths2019(months2019)
    } 
  }
```

The filter method isn't doing anything. The array stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter does not mutate the array, instead, it returns a new array so you need to capture it's value

```
const myNewArray = months2019.filter(item => item !== value)
console.log(myNewArray) //<-- Here is your filtered array
```